Cannot find play button on a web page in selenium using python

I am using Python 3.11.9 in windows with google chrome Version 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Here is the simple code
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
url = "https://onlineradiofm.in/stations/vividh-bharati"
driver.get(url)
radio_is_paused=True
while radio_is_paused:
time.sleep(30)
    play_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/svg[1]/g/circle')
    if len(play_buttons)>0:
        print(len(play_buttons),' play buttons found')
    else:
        print('play button not found')
driver.quit()

I can see that web page gets opened in a browser and play button is visible .
I am not able to find out the reason that why I get 'play button not found' ?
I have also tried xpath //*[@id="play"]/g/circle , but got same result .

Have you tried just clicking the SVG instead of the inside elements?

if I choose xpath //[@id="pause"] or //[@id="play"] then it gets found but on clicking it I get "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

Can you try clicking anywhere else on the website first? On chrome I get vividh-bharati:331 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay

This works to me play_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg#play")))

that is working . can you tell how to detect pause button ?

I got it working with https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase (pip install seleniumbase). I used ad_block_on=True to block the page ads. Then I had to interact with the site first (clicked "h1"). Finally, I used js_click on "#play circle":
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(ad_block_on=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://onlineradiofm.in/stations/vividh-bharati")
    sb.click("h1")
    sb.js_click("#play circle")
    breakpoint()

Type c and press Enter to leave the breakpoint().

i will try that .

Thanks . i installed seleniumbase . lot of colorful output . when I ran your script , it automatically downloaded chromedriver then ran the browser and showed (Pdb+) prompt below the code , why is that ?

I put in a Python breakpoint() to pause the script at the end. Type c and press Enter to continue from the breakpoint.

Thanks . Yes , i pressed c and enter as you had said in answer .
